# Cannot cast from generic to get LINQ where clause

Tags: c#, linq

OK so I've written the following function:

```
private IQueryable<LogEntry> SelectAll<T>(IEnumerable<LogEntry> logEntries, List<Expression<Func<LogEntry, bool>>> whereClause)
{
    var selectAllQuery = from l in logEntries select l;
    if (whereClause != null)
    {
        foreach (Expression<Func<LogEntry, bool>> whereStatement in whereClause)
        {
            selectAllQuery = selectAllQuery.Where(whereClause);
        }
    }
}
```

But it won't compile. It throws an error when it tries to return something at "selectAllQuery" as follows:

> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

I've tried casting this every which way I can think of to no avail. In the above code, running the initial select statement returns `selectAllQuery` of type `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<LogEntry,LogEntry>`

Clearly I'm missing something fundamental about LINQ. But what?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `selectAllQuery` is an `IEnumerable<LogEntry>` and you need it to be an `IQueryable<LogEntry>` in order to use expression trees. Try just changing the first line of the method:

```
var selectAllQuery = logEntries.AsQueryable();
```

Alternatively, compile the predicates as you go to get them into delegate form:

```
foreach (Expression<Func<LogEntry, bool>> whereStatement in whereClause)
{
    selectAllQuery = selectAllQuery.Where(whereStatement.Compile());
}
```

EDIT: Okay, the problems weren't just because of `Queryable`, but because of your naming. Let's look at this `foreach` statement:

```
foreach (Expression<Func<LogEntry, bool>> whereStatement in whereClause)
{
    selectAllQuery = selectAllQuery.Where(whereClause);
}
```

You're not using `whereStatement` anywhere in the body of the loop. You're trying to call `Where` with the entire list of clauses on each iteration. This is where better naming would help. Try this, for example:

```
private IQueryable<LogEntry> SelectAll<T>(IEnumerable<LogEntry> logEntries,
    List<Expression<Func<LogEntry, bool>>> filters)
{
    var selectAllQuery = logEntries.AsQueryable();
    if (filters != null)
    {
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            selectAllQuery = selectAllQuery.Where(filter);
        }
    }
    return selectAllQuery;
}
```

Because the parameter is now pluralized, it would look *obviously* wrong as the argument to the `Where` method - whereas the difference between `whereStatement` and `whereClause` isn't at *all* obvious as the former being singular and the latter being plural.

Comment: Well neither seems to work. There is no "Compile" method available on whereClause according to Intellisense, and changing the var to AsQueryable() I still get a similar error - Error 50 'System.Linq.IQueryable<LogEntry>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments. I did actually try the AsQueryable before posting as it seemed the obvious solution.

Comment: @Matt: Sorry, that should have been `whereStatement.Compile` - and if you used `whereStatement` in the body of the loop in the original code but with the AsQueryable, that would have worked too. Will edit with suggested name changes...

Answer (score 1):

Some times these kind of errors would get away with simple solution like adding System.Linq to the project...and referring it in the class file. Very sad that VS IDE does not help us to resolve as part of the refactor menu...